# Determine the minimum of $\int_0^\infty\left|x^3+ax^2+bx+c\right|e^{-x}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis

This question appeared on a graduate preliminary exam in real analysis.

Determine
$$\min_{a,b,c\in\mathbb{R}} \int_0^\infty\left|x^3+ax^2+bx+c\right|e^{-x}dx.$$

Comment: You should show/post an attempt at solution, so that people interested in answering know what to focus on.

Comment: This appeared on a graduate prelim?  Seriously?

Comment: @Paul It's not clear to me whether you find it remarkable because the problem's too hard to be a prelim problem or too easy. Doesn't look so easy to me - you got a solution?

Comment: Maybe I am missing something obvious, but it doesn't look easy at all.

Comment: The only approach that comes to my mind is to replace the $| x^3+ax^2+bx+c|$ term with $\sqrt{\varepsilon^2+(x^3+ax^2+bx+c)^2}$, so at least we may compute the stationary points of the perturbated problem by annihilating $\frac{\partial}{\partial a}$ and so on.

Comment: @Paul Yes, a friend of mine swears that this appeared on their graduate prelim exam.

Comment: Perhaps change the problem to $\lvert (x-a)(x-b)(x-c)\rvert e^{-x}$ assuming $a\leq b\leq c$. If $0\leq a$, then the integral can be  evaluated on the intervals $[0,a)$, $[a,b)$, $[b,c)$ $[c,\infty)$. But this yields a very cumbersome expression.

Comment: However, it looks reasonable that in order to achieve the minimum we must have a monic third-degree polynomial that is small, in absolute value, in a right neighbourhood of zero. So it looks reasonable that we must have three real non-negative roots, like @luftbahnfahrer suggested.

Comment: If the problem was $\min_{a,b,c\in\mathbb{R}} \int_0^\infty\left|x^3+ax^2+bx+c\right|^2e^{-x}dx.$, then there would be plenty of nice ways of solving it. Are you sure your friend gave you the problem correctly?

Comment: By choosing three real roots in $\frac{1}{3},\frac{4}{3},\frac{10}{3}$ I got $\min < 1.43$. Not really useful but maybe it is a starting point.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Sneaking in that $\epsilon$ might work. Of course we still have to solve problem${}_\epsilon$ and then show that the solution converges to problem${}_0$ as $\epsilon\to0$. But it's farther than I've got...

Comment: Through numerical methods in MATLAB, I got a minimum of $\approx 1.429382$ attained by $a \approx -4.996103$, $b \approx 5.965612$, and $c \approx -1.429384$. This corresponds to roots of roughly $0.319747$, $1.339821$, and $3.336535$. My guess is that this problem does not have a closed form solution, but of course, that's just a guess.

Comment: I'm now quite sure that the professor who wrote the exam did not realise the difficulty of this problem. I know who it is and will confirm with them next week.

Comment: @luftbahnfahrer What did he say?

Comment: The professor made a mistake. The problem was _intended_ to be a modification of the following problem, which has apparently appeared on previous analysis exams in the department: Compute $\min_{a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{R}}\int_{-1}^{1}(x^4−a−bx−cx^2−dx^3)^2dx$.

Comment: @JimmyK4542 I suspect that the professor who wrote the exam did indeed mean to have the integrand squared, rather than in the absolute value, as you put it. That makes the problem solvable. However, the problem on the exam did in fact appear as I originally wrote it here, which does not seem to have a closed solution.

Comment: That being said, does anyone know of any nifty tricks for solving this problem that would make it exam-worthy? I can't think of a way, beyond evaluating the integral and minimizing the resulting polynomial in (a,b,c).